# Remain rate limit tokens for my Heroku application

Tags: heroku

I am getting rate limited, so I need to know the number of remaining tokens before making the call.

See the below documentation:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#rate-limits

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't get the remaining number of requests available before making a call to Heroku's API.
However, you can retrieve that information within any request.

If you try the following request:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" -vn https://api.heroku.com/users/~
```

You will see two HTTP headers giving you the remaining number of tokens:

> Ratelimit-Multiplier: 1
>   Ratelimit-Remaining: 4499

The first one may change depending of the request you're making. Some requests are heavier than others, so they will drain your rate limits faster.
The second one is the number of tokens remaining.

If you do `Ratelimit-Multiplier * Ratelimit-Remaining`, you know how many requests to this endpoint you can still make.